# Can you run a method within HTML img src tags in Haml?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, haml, src

A rails app I'm currently working on uses ERB within an `<img>` tag to load a picture that matches the content on display as follows:

```
<img alt="Lorem Ipsum" class="lazy item-thumbnail" 
     data-img-src=<%=Suggestion.all.first.user_suggestions.second.suggestion_image_file_path%> />
```

They want this converted to Haml.

When I run this through the interpreter on http://html2haml.herokuapp.com/ it breaks as follows:

`%img.lazy.item-thumbnail{:alt => "Lorem Ipsum", "data-img-src" => "<haml_loud"}>/
"Suggestion.user_suggestions.second.suggestion_image_file_path" />`

So

1. Can I even make a call like that in Haml?
2. If yes, how?
   and
3. If not, anybody got a nice JS workaround? I'm assuming I can hack this with js function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do data- attributes with haml and rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353788/how-to-do-data-attributes-with-haml-and-rails)

Comment: If that post answered my question of whether or not I can run a method in a haml image source tag, I did not understand, and would love to know. Can you elaborate on how its a duplicate?

Comment: In your original the Erb content is just a string, it doesn’t actually do anything. Is that the real code?

Comment: mmm, that was a glaring oversight. the actual code was ><%=Suggestion.all.first.user_suggestions.second.suggestion_image_file_path%> and yes, thats just a string. I've got what they want working now. No worries, but thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

```
<%="Suggestion.user_suggestions.second.suggestion_image_file_path"%>
```

change to:

```
"<%=Suggestion.user_suggestions.second.suggestion_image_file_path%>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
%img.lazy.item-thumbnail{ alt:"Lorem Ipsum", 'data-img-src': "#{Suggestion.user_suggestions.second.suggestion_image_file_path}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to to just run the method in the controller and set the value equal to the instance variable @first_image. Once done, that variable can be use in the view as follows

```
%img.lazy.item-thumbnail{:alt => "Lorem Ipsum", "data-img-src" => @first_image}
```

If anybody comes up with something better, I'd be happy to give a check.

Answer (score 0):

Solution? Don't rely too much on auto-converters and learn some haml :)

```
%img.lazy.item-thumbnail{:alt => "Lorem Ipsum", 
                         "data-img-src" => Suggestion.user_suggestions.second.suggestion_image_file_path}
```